# Unable to serialize JavaScript object properly

Tags: javascript, serialization

```
var o = { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" }
console.log(o);
console.log(escape(o));
```

The first `console.log` shows `Object { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" }`,

the second: `%5Bobject%20Object%5D (i.e. [object Object])`

How to serialize an object properly without any plugings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize & deserialize Javascript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608545/how-to-serialize-deserialize-javascript-objects)

Comment: @Travis J: Seems to be true. Didn't find it at the beginning. Would you like me to delete this question? P.S. The answer to my question looks more clear, free of unnecessary words.

Comment: No need to delete it, the community will decide :)

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to use [**JSON**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON) serialization:

```
var serialized = JSON.stringify(o);
// "{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}"
```

You can read about browser compatibility at **MDN**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Paul - Note also, this is not a plugin but a javascript feature. +1

Comment: @Paul `JSON` object is available in all modern browsers. For the old ones check a shim at **MDN** (see link in the answer).