# Any way to cache layout of ExtJS application on server side?

Tags: php, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Is there any method to cache an HTML-code of ExtJS components with further initializing it (binding events and so on) so that I can send it by PHP inside one solid HTML file?
In other words I want server to send already pre-rendered page.

Comment: I see the only way - to make visually similar HTML (without details and functional). And after rendering hide it and than show rendered fully-functional component. So user won't see delay during loading component.

Answer (score 0):

If your idea is to capture the memory state of the client application that seems like a bold project, to say the least. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608545/how-to-serialize-deserialize-javascript-objects).

If what you want is to have all you application embedded in one single HTML file, that is possible. Just concatenate all you Javascript (including Ext's code) and put it in a script tag, and do the same with the CSS and wrap in into a style tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <style>
      /* All your CSS here */
    </style>
    <script>
      // All you javascript here
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, if you care about the maintainability of you code, you should automate this procedure...