# Serializing a JavaScript Object to JSON returns "{}", but why?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, stringify

Hello StackOverflowers,

I'm implementing a LocalStorage system for my web application.

But my pity is that all the objects in the Model abstraction layer have to be serialized.

I am aware that functions don't get serialized when the object is converted to JSON.

I was about to use [Option 1 described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579852/best-approach-for-creating-an-object-from-deserializing?lq=1). (Which is, creating a 'static' method which returns a brand new object including the functions).

However, the problem is that even the non-function members of the objects don't get converted as well.

For example at divvie.textContent = JSON.stringify( coffee );, divvie.textContent becomes "{}".

Why? What's going on?

Sample code, not my real application but the situation is much the same:
    
    
        
            Check Coffee

```
                var coffee = new Coffee( "0001", "DE Red Coarse",
                    "Douwe Egberts, red & coarse grounded." );
                coffee.addSugarCube( "0x0F_BROWN", "15" );
                coffee.addSugarCube( "0x0C_WHITE", "12" );

                var divvie = document.getElementById( "run" );
                divvie.textContent = JSON.stringify( coffee );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

/**
 * @class This class represents a coffee.
 *
 * @param {String} id
 * @param {String} name
 * @param {String} description
 * @returns {Coffee}
 */
function Coffee( id, name, description )
{
    var sugarCubes = new Array();

    var maxAmountOfSweetness = 0;

    /**
     * @returns {String}
     */
    this.getId = function()
    {
        return id;
    };

    /**
     * @returns {String}
     */
    this.getName = function()
    {
        return name;
    };

    /**
     * @returns {String}
     */
    this.getDescription = function()
    {
        return description;
    };

    /**
     * @param {String} sugarCubeId
     * @param {Number} amountOfSweetness
     */
    this.addSugarCube = function( sugarCubeId, amountOfSweetness )
    {
        /// First check if this sugarCube is already in our coffee.
        var sugarCubeFound = false;

        for( var i = 0; i < sugarCubes.length; i++ )
        {
            if( sugarCubes[ i ].getId() === sugarCubeId )
            {
                sugarCubeFound = true;

                i = sugarCubes.length;
            }
        }

        if( !sugarCubeFound )
        {
            /// Oh Sweet! A new sugar cube to add in our coffee!
            sugarCubes.push( new SugarCube( sugarCubeId, amountOfSweetness ) );
            maxAmountOfSweetness = Math.max( maxAmountOfSweetness, amountOfSweetness );
        }
    };

    /**
     * @param {String} sugarCubeId
     * @returns {SugarCube}
     */
    this.getSugarCube = function( sugarCubeId )
    {
        for( var i = 0; i < sugarCubes.length; i++ )
        {
            if( sugarCubes[ i ].getId() === sugarCubeId )
            {
                return sugarCubes[ i ];
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * @returns {Boolean} True when the amount of sugar cubes in this coffee is 1 or more,
     * false when not.
     */
    this.isSweet = function()
    {
        if( 0 < sugarCubes.length )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
}

/**
 * @class This class represents a sugar cube
 *
 * @param {String} id
 * @param {Number} amountOfSweetness
 * @returns {SugarCube}
 */
function SugarCube( id, amountOfSweetness )
{
    /**
     * @returns {String}
     */
    this.getId = function()
    {
        return id;
    };

    /**
     * @returns {Number}
     */
    this.getAmountOfSweetness = function()
    {
        return amountOfSweetness;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only properties on instances created by the `Coffee` constructor seem to be the methods, which have no *JSON* representation (because they're *functions*). Your *data* is all kept as `var`iables or parameters within the closures created. These are not *properties* and therefore again not something that *JSON* is designed for.

To get it working as you expect, you'll either need to write your own `toJSON` method, or move your data from `var`s to properties

For example, using properties

```
function Coffee(id, name, description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.sugarCubes = [];
    this.maxAmountOfSweetness = 0;
}
// and now you could even move the methods into the prototype
Coffee.prototype = {
    getId: function () {return this.id;}
    // etc

};
// new Coffee() is now JSON-able
```

---

You probably used `var` to "hide" the data so it was only exposed through your methods, so the other way is to add a new method which converts it to *JSON*, e.g.

```
// in Coffee
this.toJSON = function (a, b) {
    var o = {
        id: id,
        name: name
        // etc
    };
    return JSON.stringify(o, a, b);
};
```

Comment: The parameter "a" and "b" of this.toJSON() are "replacer" and "space" in JSON.stringify(), am I correct?   <br /> 
   <br />
PS: You're right about my use of var and this here. I'm raised with Java and C++, so I use "var" as the "private" access modifier and "this" as the "public" access modifier.<br />

Comment: @RoestVrijStaal indeed, you don't _have_ to support them but I thought why not